# Relative path with last restful parameter

Tags: php, html

This seems like it should be a simple fix.

I have a restful PHP backend and have a setup where I can have a URL:

`site.com/profile/100/photos/`

and

`site.com/me/photos`

The photos controller will be the same for both and some of the front end is shared for both as well.

My question is the following:

If I'm at this URL : `site.com/profile/100`

and I add an href:

```
<a href="photos">Photos</a>
```

it is taking me to `site.com/profile/photos` instead of `site.com/profile/100/photos`. How do I get it to go add the URL after the 100?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]/photos";
```

Comment: +1 - ...or on the client side: `<a href="#" onclick="window.location = window.location.pathname + '/photos">Photos</a>` - but it should be done on the server side.

Comment: Ahh. yes. This would normally work, but the links I'm pulling in are coming in via Ajax, so the php self is a different script in a different location.